# connect view to content type

Tags: views, nodes, theming

I am working on a drupal 7 installation. This has a content type called Team. In `Structure > Views` there is a view called Team content. In the folder structure there is also a corresponding view file named `node--view--team.tpl.php` which renders the Team content.

My task is to duplicate the content type to a new content type called Managers. So I created a new content type called Managers with all the same fields as in Team. I cloned the Team view as well. I then copied over the team tpl file into a new file named `node--view--managers.tpl.php`.

The problem I am facing is that the manager tpl file is not used when drupal renders the content. It falls back to node.tpl.php - however the design of this page is not how I want it.

What am I missing here? Is there any place in the code/ admin interface where I can specify that node--view--manager.tpl.php should be used instead of node.tpl.php?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your theme may create `node--view--CONTENTTYPE.tpl.php` but per content type theme suggestions are not provided out of the box. Your theme layer or a custom module typically provides the theme suggestion, there are a ton of tutorials online about this.

I recommend installing Devel Themer to inspect the View theme template file usage on the page for Teams. Then see why/if the Managers is failing by visiting that page.

Then look through your theme sourcecode and custom modules to see what is providing the `hook_theme` suggestions.